# RuntimeError: torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy and torch.nn.BCELoss are unsafe to autocast

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I am trying to implement [U^2 Net for Salient Object detection](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net). Since this code is not optimised for training, following [this official documentation for AMP](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html#typical-mixed-precision-training), I have made some changes to the original code [in my fork](https://github.com/deshwalmahesh/U-2-Net) to check the effects.

I have used the code exactly and when you [run my version of training code on colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vyHmjBVnkTlIadsvd9ykNLg6vkiJ6szJ?usp=sharing)
as :

```
! git clone https://github.com/deshwalmahesh/U-2-Net
%cd ./U-2-Net/
!python u2net_train.py
```

It'll throw you some error. The whole stack is posted in the end. I dug up and found that it is due to the custom loss function as [`muti_bce_loss_fusion`](https://github.com/deshwalmahesh/U-2-Net/blob/99a4c94dbfa280e4f157b2983100f70261f6829e/u2net_train.py#L31) which the authors have used as:

```
bce_loss = nn.BCELoss(size_average=True)

def muti_bce_loss_fusion(d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, labels_v):

    loss0 = bce_loss(d0,labels_v)
    loss1 = bce_loss(d1,labels_v)
    loss2 = bce_loss(d2,labels_v)
    loss3 = bce_loss(d3,labels_v)
    loss4 = bce_loss(d4,labels_v)
    loss5 = bce_loss(d5,labels_v)
    loss6 = bce_loss(d6,labels_v)

    loss = loss0 + loss1 + loss2 + loss3 + loss4 + loss5 + loss6
    return loss0, loss
```

Also, [in the last line i.e line 526 of the model definition](https://github.com/deshwalmahesh/U-2-Net/blob/master/model/u2net.py), the model returns 7 sigmoid values which are passed to the loss function.

```
F.sigmoid(d0), F.sigmoid(d1), F.sigmoid(d2), F.sigmoid(d3), F.sigmoid(d4), F.sigmoid(d5), F.sigmoid(d6)
```

Now what can be done to avoid this error?

**Error trace**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:780: UserWarning: Note that order of the arguments: ceil_mode and return_indices will changeto match the args list in nn.MaxPool2d in a future release.
  warnings.warn("Note that order of the arguments: ceil_mode and return_indices will change"
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:3704: UserWarning: nn.functional.upsample is deprecated. Use nn.functional.interpolate instead.
  warnings.warn("nn.functional.upsample is deprecated. Use nn.functional.interpolate instead.")
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:1944: UserWarning: nn.functional.sigmoid is deprecated. Use torch.sigmoid instead.
  warnings.warn("nn.functional.sigmoid is deprecated. Use torch.sigmoid instead.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "u2net_train.py", line 148, in <module>
    loss2, loss = muti_bce_loss_fusion(d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, labels_v)
  File "u2net_train.py", line 33, in muti_bce_loss_fusion
    loss0 = bce_loss(d0,labels_v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 612, in forward
    return F.binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3065, in binary_cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight, reduction_enum)
RuntimeError: torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy and torch.nn.BCELoss are unsafe to autocast.
Many models use a sigmoid layer right before the binary cross entropy layer.
In this case, combine the two layers using torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
or torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.  binary_cross_entropy_with_logits and BCEWithLogits are
safe to autocast.
```

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why it was due to unstable nature of `Sigmoid + BCE`. Referring to documentation and `torch` community, all I had to to do was to replace the models from `F.sigmoid(d0)...` to `d0.....` and then in turn replace `nn.BCELoss(size_average=True)` with `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(size_average=True)`. Now the model is running fine.